# Split up WMI Objects in Powershell

Tags: powershell, scripting, wmi, wmi-query

I'm new to PowerShell and I try to read some monitor/display infos from clients.

I put together this script:

```
param(
[string]$ComputerName
)

$objWMi = get-wmiobject -namespace root\WMI -ComputerName $ComputerName -class WmiMonitorID | select WeekOfManufacture, YearOfManufacture, UserFriendlyName, SerialNumberID, ManufacturerName

$Userfn = ForEach-Object {($objWMi.UserFriendlyName -ne 0 | foreach {[char]$_}) -join"";}
$SerialNum = ForEach-Object {($objWMi.SerialNumberID -ne 0 | foreach {[char]$_}) -join"";}
$ManuName = ForEach-Object {($objWMi.ManufacturerName -ne 0 | foreach {[char]$_}) -join"";}
$Weekom = $objWMi.WeekOfManufacture
$Yearom = $objWMi.YearOfManufacture


Write-Host "1: $Userfn  | $ManuName | $SerialNum | $Weekom | $Yearom" 


Exit 0
```

It is called with `.\myscript.ps1 -ComputerName clientdnsname` and returns something like this:

`1: P22W-5 ECO  | FUS | YE7XXXXX | 46 | 2008`.

Works like a charm, exactly what I need. There is one exception: if some client has more than one monitor attached the script returns something like this:

`1: HP E272qHP E272q  | HWPHWP | CNKXXXXCCNKYYYY | 40 40 | 2015 2015`

How can I modify the output to split the result up if there is more than one monitor and output

`1: HP E272q | HWP| CNKXXXX | 40 | 2015 2: HP E272q | HWP| CNKXXXX | 40 | 2015`

The variables contain the infos for all monitors and I have no idea how to avoid this or how to split this up in one value per variable. 
Any ideas much appreciated!

EDIT: I need the result returned in **one row** like above because I feed this to another program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this script: http://www.activexperts.com/admin/scripts/wmiscripts/powershell/0073/

It doesn't handle converting the text like you do, but that's easy to rectify with the code you already have.

This modification should be pretty close to what you need:

```
function byteArrayToString($byteArray)
{
    if ($byteArray.Count -gt 0){
        return ($byteArray -ne 0 | foreach {[char]$_}) -join""
    }
    return "N/A"
}

$strComputer = "."

$objWMi = get-wmiobject -namespace root\WMI -computername localhost -Query "Select * from WmiMonitorID"

foreach ($obj in $objWmi)
{
    $Userfn = byteArrayToString($obj.UserFriendlyName)
    $SerialNum = byteArrayToString($obj.SerialNumberID)
    $ManuName = byteArrayToString($obj.ManufacturerName)
    $Weekom = $obj.WeekOfManufacture
    $Yearom = $obj.YearOfManufacture
    Write-Host "1: $Userfn  | $ManuName | $SerialNum | $Weekom | $Yearom" 
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I've seen this script before. Unfortunately I need the result returned in one row because I process the result in another program...Edited my post to clear things up. I also put a `foreach` loop around `write-host` in my script. This also outputs the row with doubled entries but just does it two times....

Comment: I updated the code to output on a single line for you. The "foreach" loop around your variable assignments is what was causing the problem for you.

Comment: Yay. I tried with a  `foreach` loop around the variables too but did not removed `ForEach-Object` at the same time. Thanks!

Comment: I added a little function to do the string conversion. This way if you come to an empty value, it won't throw an error. DarkLite1's solution is more elegant though. So ideally, I would combine that function with his response.

Answer (score 2):

I feel the need to add an extra answer. Please keep in mind that `Write-Host` is NOT the way to go. As Don Jones [explains](http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/donjones/archive/2012/04/06/2012-scripting-games-commentary-stop-using-write-host.aspx) it kills puppies and there are plenty of better ways to achieve what you want.

First of all, by generating a `PSCustomObject` you can do a lot more.

Some examples:

```
Function Get-MonitorInfo {
    Param (
        [String]$ComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME
    )

    # For ease of reading the code we create a hashtable which we use wit 'Get-WmiObject', this is called 'Splatting'
    $WmiParams = @{
        Namespace    = 'root\WMI'
        ComputerName = $ComputerName
        Class        = 'WmiMonitorID'
    }

    # First we collect all the results in one variabla
    $Objects = Get-WmiObject @WmiParams | Select-Object WeekOfManufacture, YearOfManufacture, 
        UserFriendlyName, SerialNumberID, ManufacturerName

    # Then for each object in the variable '$Objects' we generate one line of output (an object)
    foreach ($Object in $Objects) {

        # The generated object will contain the following
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            FriendlyName      = ($Object.UserFriendlyName | ForEach-Object {[Char]$_}) -join ''
            SN                = ($Object.SerialNumberID | ForEach-Object {[Char]$_}) -join ''
            ManufacturerName  = ($Object.ManufacturerName | ForEach-Object {[char]$_}) -join ''
            ManufacturingWeek = $Object.WeekOfManufacture
            ManufacturingYear = $Object.YearOfManufacture
        }
    }
}

$Result = Get-MonitorInfo

# List all monitors:
$Result

# Only list Monitors with a FriendlyName starting with HP:
$Result | where {$_.FriendlyName -like 'HP*'}

# Only list Monitors with a FriendlyName starting with HP and show me the SN:
$Result | where {$_.FriendlyName -like 'HP*'} | Select-Object SN

# Count how many monitors we have on one machine:
$Result.Count

# Export everything to a file
$Result | Out-File -FilePath "$env:TEMP\Monitors.txt"
Start-Process "$env:TEMP\Monitors.txt"
```

As you can see, all these things would be difficult when only using `Write-Host`. Hopefully the examples above made it a bit more clear why you should not be using `Write-Host` in this case.

Comment: Thank you! I did not know about this. I'm proccesing this script with another program which is executing the script and expects a string as a result printed to standard output (in one row).

Comment: You're welcome, hope you learned something. Output to a string is also possible: `$Result | Select @{N='String';E={"$($_.FriendlyName) | $($_.SN) | $($_.ManufacturerName) | $($_.ManufacturingWeek) | $($_.ManufacturingYear)"}} | Out-String` or if you mean viewing the content on one line you can also do `$Result | Format-Table`.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! The hashtable does not seem to work, it always returns the infos from localhost...Also is there a way to just return this one line? Your first example outputs `String                                                                                                              
------                                                                                                                                                                                        
P22W-5 ECO    | YE7XXXXX       | FUS              | 46 | 2008 ` How can I avoid the whole "String"-line?

Comment: With an object everything is possible, please try this: `Get-MonitorInfo -ComputerName MyPCNameHere | Select @{N='String';E={"$($_.FriendlyName) | $($_.SN) | $($_.ManufacturerName) | $($_.ManufacturingWeek) | $($_.ManufacturingYear)"}} | Select -ExpandProperty String`

Answer (score 1):

I tried to propose the below as a modification to DarkLite1's answer, but apparently somebody thought it was "deliberately destructive" and rejected it . . .

In answer to your question, duenni, the below modification to DarkLite1's code will give you the ability to output the data in the format you're looking for.

```
Function byteArrayToString($byteArray)
{
    if ($byteArray.Count -gt 0){
        return ($byteArray -ne 0 | foreach {[char]$_}) -join""
    }
    return "N/A"
}

Function Get-MonitorInfo {
    Param (
        [String]$ComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME
    )

    # For ease of reading the code we create a hashtable which we use wit 'Get-WmiObject', this is called 'Splatting'
    $WmiParams = @{
        Namespace    = 'root\WMI'
        ComputerName = $ComputerName
        Class        = 'WmiMonitorID'
    }

    # First we collect all the results in one variabla
    $Objects = Get-WmiObject @WmiParams | Select-Object WeekOfManufacture, YearOfManufacture, 
        UserFriendlyName, SerialNumberID, ManufacturerName

    # Then for each object in the variable '$Objects' we generate one line of output (an object)
    foreach ($Object in $Objects) {

        # The generated object will contain the following
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            FriendlyName      = byteArrayToString($Object.UserFriendlyName)
            SN                = byteArrayToString($Object.SerialNumberID)
            ManufacturerName  = byteArrayToString($Object.ManufacturerName)
            ManufacturingWeek = $Object.WeekOfManufacture
            ManufacturingYear = $Object.YearOfManufacture
        } | Add-Member -MemberType ScriptMethod -Name ToString -Force -Value {
            "1: $($this.FriendlyName) | $($this.ManufacturerName) | $($this.SN) | $($this.ManufacturingWeek) | $($this.ManufacturingYear)"
        } -PassThru
    }
}

$Result = Get-MonitorInfo

# List all monitors:
$Result

# List all monitors as formatted strings
foreach ($monitor in $Result) {$monitor.ToString()}

# Only list Monitors with a FriendlyName starting with HP:
$Result | where {$_.FriendlyName -like 'HP*'}

# Only list Monitors with a FriendlyName starting with HP and show me the SN:
$Result | where {$_.FriendlyName -like 'HP*'} | Select-Object SN

# Count how many monitors we have on one machine:
$Result.Count

# Export everything to a file
$Result | Out-File -FilePath "$env:TEMP\Monitors.txt"
Start-Process "$env:TEMP\Monitors.txt"
```

The new function can be called as follows:

`foreach ($monitor in $Result) {$monitor.ToString()}`

Comment: Thanks! Does it work for you? If i call it with `.\myscript.ps1 -ComputerName hostxy` it alway returns the infos from localhost. I tried to modify `$Result = Get-MonitorInfo` to `$Result = Get-MonitorInfo -ComputerName $ComputerName` but this won't work.

Comment: Well, I think I got this. Have to use another `Param`-block at the beginning of the ps1-file, like: `param(
[string]$HostName
)`. This param is then passed to the function with `$Result = Get-MonitorInfo($HostName)`. Then I can call the script like this `myscript.ps1 -HostName hostxy`

Comment: You can do that, or you could just dot-source the ps1 file in, then call

`Get-MonitorInfo -ComputerName whatever`

For details, check out this page and search for "dot source":
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847841.aspx